# How to import python variable in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, python

I have a shell script like below.
If I have a test.py that has a variable `a=5`, how can I import the variable to the following shell script?

```
python test.py
b=10

if [ $a == $b ]
then
   echo "a is equal to b"
else
   echo "a is not equal to b"
fi
```

Comment: using `[ $a == $b ]` is going to give you trouble you should use `[[ $a == $b ]]` or `[ "$a" == "$b" ]` and then only if `$a` or `$b` are strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a variable from your python script. Put at your python script:

```
a="something"
print(a)
```

And at your shell script:

```
a=$(python script.py)
b="something"

if [ "$a" == "$b" ]; then
... 
... 
...
```